# JavaScriptのPromiseにタイムアウトを追加するスクリプトで引数 ...argsに何が入っているか分からない。

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptのPromiseについて勉強しているのですが、下記のスクリプトで使われている引数 `...args` に何が格納されているのかよくわかりません。 google chromeのコンソールにコピペして実行すると`console.log()`出力しようとしても定義されていないと出ます。
プログラム自体はカウントダウン後、ロケットが発車した後にタイムアウトでエラーを引き起こします。
よろしくお願いします。

```js
function countdown(seconds) {
    return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        const timeoutIds =[];
        for(let i=seconds; i>=0; i--) {
            timeoutIds.push(setTimeout(
                function() {
                    if(i===13) {
                        timeoutIds.forEach(clearTimeout);
                        onRejected(new Error(`${i}という数は不吉過ぎます`));
                    }
                    else if(i>0){
                        console.log(i + '...');
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("GO!");
                        onFulfilled();
                    }
                }, 
                (seconds-i)*1000));
        }
    });
}

function launch() {
    return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) return; //ここを追加した。
        console.log("発射!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            onFulfilled("周回軌道に乗った!");
        }, 2*1000); /*超高速ロケット*/
    });
}

function addTimeout(fn,
                                        period
                                        ) {
    if(period === undefined) period = 1000;
    return function(...args) {
        return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
            const timeoutId = setTimeout(onRejected, period, new Error("プロミス タイムアウト"));
                fn(...args)
                .then(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onFulfilled(...args);
                })
                .catch(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onRejected(...args);
                    console.log(...args); //Uncaught ReferenceError: args is not defined
                });
        });
    }
}

countdown(3)
    .then(addTimeout(launch, 4*1000))
    .then(function(msg) {/*関数launch内のonFulfilledの引数がmsgに渡る*/
        console.log(msg);
    })//カウントダウンが13以上だとonRejectedが実行され下記のcatchに処理が移る。
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error("管制塔、管制塔。トラブル発生..." + err);
})
```

#### 参照

Ethan Brown. Learning JavaScript, 3rd Edition. O'Reilly. イーサン ブラウン ムシャ ヒロユキ ムシャ ルミ (訳) 2017.

Comment: 参考:[Rest parameters - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにもありますが `...args` 自体の説明はMDNに譲ります。

残余引数 - JavaScript | MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

---

`function addTimeout()`は任意のPromiseを返す関数を受け取って、そのPromiseにtimeoutの機能を追加して返すためのラッパー(Wrapper)です。(当該書籍は持っていませんが…)

このラッパーが返す関数の引数を、受け取った関数と同じ引数にしたいところですが、任意の関数 `fn` が渡されるため、引数の個数などが特定できません。

そのため、`...args` を使用して引数すべてを参照し、それを `fn` に[スプレッド構文](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)を使用してすべてそのまま渡すことで実現しています。

```js
    return function(...args) {
        return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {

            fn(...args)
```

引数がない関数を渡した場合、`args` は空配列になります。

```js
function foo() { return 'Hello'; }

function wrapper(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(args);
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

const r = wrapper(foo)();
console.log(r);
```

---

`.then(function(...args)` の `...args` には、`fn` (実際には`launch()`)が返したPromiseが成功した時の戻り値が入ります。なので、タイムアウト処理を停止後、その値を全て`onFulfilled`にスプレッド構文で渡してPromiseを正常終了させます。

質問文のコードの場合、実際には`"周回軌道に乗った!"`が1つだけ入るはずです。

```js
    return function(...args) {
        return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {

            fn(...args)
                .then(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onFulfilled(...args);
                })
```

---

さて、`.catch(function(...args)`ですが、この `...args` には `launch()` が返したPromiseが失敗した時のErrorが入ります。

```js
            fn(...args)
                .then(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onFulfilled(...args);
                })
                .catch(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onRejected(...args);
                    console.log(...args);
                });
```

ですが、`launch()` の実装を見ればわかる通り、この関数は `onRejected` の呼び出しもしませんし、Errorのthrowもしないので、少なくとも質問文のコードではここに到達することはあり得ません。

おそらく別の所で出た`console.log()`と混同したか、別の場所にかけたbreakpointからcatchに書かれたfunction内の`args`を参照したため`args is not defined`になったものと推測します。

例えば、以下のようにコードを書き換えれば、`.catch()`に到達し、引数にもErrorが入っていることが確認できるはずです。

```js
function launch() {
    return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        // 必ずエラーを起こす
        if (true) { throw new Error("error in launch!!!"); }

        console.log("発射!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            onFulfilled("周回軌道に乗った!");
        }, 2*1000); /*超高速ロケット*/
    });
}

function addTimeout(fn, period) {
    if(period === undefined) period = 1000;
    return function(...args) {
        return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
            const timeoutId = setTimeout(onRejected, period, new Error("プロミス タイムアウト"));
                fn(...args)
                .then(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onFulfilled(...args);
                })
                .catch(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    onRejected(...args);

                    // throw した Error を参照する
                    console.info(args[0].toString());
                });
        });
    }
}

addTimeout(launch, 4*1000)();
```

---

> プログラム自体はカウントダウン後、ロケットが発車した後にタイムアウトでエラーを引き起こします。

質問文のスニペットを複数回実行すればわかりますが、だいたい50%の確率で成功したりタイムアウトしたりするはずです。

これは以下のコードにより、50%の確率で`onFulfilled`も`onRejected`も呼ばれずにこの非同期処理が完了しないまま時間経過して、`addTimeout()`内でセットした`setTimeout()`が発火して`"プロミス タイムアウト"`になるためです。

```js
function launch() {
    return new Promise(function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) return; //ここを追加した。
```

Promiseが必ず正しく成功または失敗するようにコーディングするのはプログラマーの責務です。ただし人間誰しもミスをしてしまうもので、このように適切にPromiseが終了しないコーディングをしてしまうことが稀にあります。

例えばESLintで `no-promise-executor-return` ルールを設定しておくと、このようなコーディングミスを発見することができます。

no-promise-executor-return - Rules - ESLint - Pluggable JavaScript linter
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-promise-executor-return#disallow-returning-values-from-promise-executor-functions-no-promise-executor-return

Comment: 返信が遅くなりすいません。とても分かりやすい説明ありがとうございます。コードを少しずつ動作させて理解したいと思います。